# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mageproductid ' Magento

Tags: magento

Error en Magento al crear un producto, esto pasa el crear o editar un producto.

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mageproductid ' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `marketplace_product` AS `main_table` WHERE (`mageproductid ` = '2195')

Trace:
#0 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/huancayovende/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Observer.php(251): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1374): Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer->SaveProduct(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1353): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer), 'SaveProduct', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/Mage.php(451): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#14 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(682): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#15 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(736): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->_initProductSave()
#16 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#17 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#18 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/huancayovende/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/huancayovende/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Aun que estaria bien que añadas mas detalles, no solo el error, parece que cuando utilizas la columna en el where esta añadiendo algun espacio extra: `('mageproductid ' = '2195')`

Comment: Vale gracias ya encontré el problema linea 250 y 259 de magento app\code\local\Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Observer.php